# navigating spreadsheet xml by python

Tags: python, lxml

I am working on a task building a reference map for a given formula in a XML spreadsheet. For instance, for the following row:

```
<row>
    <cell></cell>
    <cell></cell>
    <cell index="5"></cell>
    <cell></cell>
    <cell></cell>
    <cell index="9"></cell>
    <cell></cell>
    ......
</row>
```

if I use `enumerate(row.findall("cell"))` it will return `a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.  However, the attribute `index` gives information for a specific cell.  That is, instead of `a` I should get `b=[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]` (note the third cell is *5*, so it changes the enumeration, similar thing happen when the index is *9* later).

How do i get from `a` to `b`? I'd like a more Pythonic program. What I have now my C-like syntax (which I am kind of bored of):

```
testcases = [[1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 9, 8], [5, 4, 5, 9, 8], [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 9]]

for cells in testcases:
    first = None
    for i, c in enumerate(cells):
        if c>i+1:
            first = c

        if i>0 and c < cells[i-1]:
            cells[i]=cells[i-1]+1
        elif i>0 and c> cells[i-1]+1 and first is None:
            first=c
            for j in range(i)[::-1]:
                cells[j]=c-1
                c=c-1
    print(cells)
```

Comment: The wording is a bit hard to parse.  Please, could you reword it and be a bit more explicit with your example and context?

Comment: The code in the example does not seem to try to solve the problem.  How did you construct `testcases` from the example given in the context?

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your question completely but this may be a starting point to what you need:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 9, 8], [5, 4, 5, 9, 8], [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 9]]

for rowid, cellid, cell in [(rowid, cellid, cell) for rowid, row in enumerate(matrix) for cellid, cell in enumerate(row)]:
    print "matrix[%d, %d]: %s" % (rowid, cellid, cell)
```

This will traverse the whole matrix, printing all the cells and giving you access to all the rows and cells ids.

Answer (score 0):

I think `enumerate` deviates a bit the problem you want to solve.  You have to consider that
`findall` returns a list of `elements`, from which you can retrieve their attributes and use them to fill the values.

So, given the XML sample you gave and the output you expects, the following snippet allows you to get a list of cells considering the index (whenever a cell has it):

```
from lxml import etree

tag = etree.fromstring('''<row>
                             <cell></cell><cell></cell>
                             <cell index="5">
                             </cell><cell></cell><cell></cell>
                             <cell index="9"></cell>
                             <cell></cell>
                          </row>''')

index = 1
result = []
for cell in tag.findall('cell'):
    index = int(cell.attrib['index']) if cell.attrib.has_key('index') else index
    result.append(index)
    index += 1

print result
```

The result is:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I'd like to know how from [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10] i can get =[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]. algorithm is,  for a number not eq index(number) in the list, reindex it e.g. to 5 for the following numbers until next index 9

Comment: It looks like a XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem